# Print bibliography, anonymising the authors

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I have a pretty weird request. I would like to print a bibliography (using biber and biblatex) but I'd like to remove all the author information. That is, I'd like to print a bibliography, without identifying any of the authors. What's the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following removes all name fields from all `.bib` entries

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[foreach=setnames]{
      \step[fieldset=\regexp{$MAPLOOP}, null]
    }
  }
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,worman,geer}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: The Cast of Character. Style in Greek Literature. Austin: University of Texas Press, 2002.//‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4 (1998), pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.//[3] ‘Earl, Saint, Bishop, Skald – and Music. The Orkney Earldom of the Twelfth Century. A Musicological Study’. PhD thesis. Uppsala: Uppsala Universitet, 1985.]